# The attribute model is not defined - Magento search

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

During an extended series of SQL injection attempts my client disabled the Mage_CatalogSearch module output (sys->config->advanced->advanced).

The problem is that since it's been re-enabled any search query no longer works and results in the following error.

Has anyone seen this before or can perhaps steer me in the right direction?

```
The attribute model is not defined

Trace:
#0 /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/Abstract.php(239): Mage::throwException('The attribute m...')
#1 /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs/app/code/local/Mana/Filters/Model/Filter/Attribute.php(61): Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Abstract->getAttributeModel()
#2 /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs/app/code/local/Mana/Filters/Model/Filter/Attribute.php(243): Mana_Filters_Model_Filter_Attribute->_getItemsData()
#3 /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/Abstract.php(120): Mana_Filters_Model_Filter_Attribute->_initItems()
#4 /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/Abstract.php(109): Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Abstract->getItems()
#5 /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs/app/code/local/Mana/Filters/Block/Filter.php(77): Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Abstract->getItemsCount()
#6 /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Layer/View.php(218): Mana_Filters_Block_Filter->getItemsCount()
#7 /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs/app/code/local/Mana/Filters/Block/View.php(156): Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_View->canShowOptions()
#8 /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs/app/code/local/Mana/Filters/Block/View.php(181): Mana_Filters_Block_View->_canShowBlockInCategory()
#9 /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs/app/code/local/Mana/Filters/Block/View.php(150): Mana_Filters_Block_View->_canShowBlockInSearch()
#10 /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs/app/design/frontend/pros/default/template/catalog/layer/view.phtml(34): Mana_Filters_Block_View->canShowBlock()
#11 /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/var/www/vhosts...')
#12 /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/proswi...')
#13 /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#14 /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#15 /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#16 /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#17 /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(582): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#18 /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(526): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('left', true)
#19 /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs/app/design/frontend/pros/default/template/page/2columns-left.phtml(51): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('left')
#20 /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/var/www/vhosts...')
#21 /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/proswi...')
#22 /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#23 /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#24 /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#25 /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#26 /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/controllers/ResultController.php(80): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#27 /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(419): Mage_CatalogSearch_ResultController->indexAction()
#28 /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#29 /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#30 /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#31 /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#32 /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs/index.php(80): Mage::run('', 'store')
#33 {main}
```

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce your error. Sure no modules were disabled in modules xml-files? `Disable module output` means just that. Blocks aren't rendered anymore but all models remain available. This error might occur when a custom attribute model is used and the corresponding module is disabled. Magento stores this models in `eav_attribute`, so check this table for non default models. From the errormessage I saw you use Mana_Filters module. This module uses an own table `m_attribute`. Check this table also.

Comment: Nothing was touched in /app/etc/modules. I'm not sure which row I should be looking for in eav_attribute but here is a snap of m_attribute : http://bit.ly/ZSCPIS

Comment: It's hard to tell without knowing the missing model. Add some logging to `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/Abstract.php` in `getAttributeModel()`. Tried to disable the mana modules?

Comment: Hi Simon...3 errors to share

Comment: 2013-06-16T17:23:33+00:00 ERR (3): Recoverable Error: Argument 3 passed to Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Abstract::_canUpdateAttribute() must be an array, null given, called in /var/www/vhosts/pro/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php on line 1225 and defined  in /var/www/vhosts/pro/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Abstract.php on line 543

Comment: 2013-06-16T17:23:33+00:00 ERR (3): Recoverable Error: Argument 3 passed to Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract::_canUpdateAttribute() must be an array, null given, called in /var/www/vhosts/pro/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Abstract.php on line 545 and defined  in /var/www/vhosts/pro/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php on line 1254

Comment: 2013-06-16T17:23:33+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given  in /var/www/vhosts/pro/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php on line 1256

Answer (score 1):

If any one in the future is going to face this same problem with the Mana Dev layered navigation bar this might help. You are seeing this error because you have deleted an attribute from the system which was being used by mana dev. Now Mana dev plugin keeps a copy of the attribute used in layered navigation or search, if you deleted an attribute without disabling for search and layered navigation, Mana Dev plugin will try to find this plugin and will not be able to process the attribute which was deleted.

To resolve it just re create the attribute in the backend but do not enable for layered navigation or search. This error will go away.

Answer (score 1):

Just reindex all Data (System > Index Management)